# Which trekking shoes to get for trekking in Costa Rica

Tags: hiking, clothing, costa-rica

I'm about to travel to Costa Rica, on a trip that will include a serious hike.
My travel company recommends hiking shoes in category B/C for this trip.

However, when I search for this type of shoes I always end up with heavy leather GoreTex shoes from companies like Hanwag and Mammut. (Like the popular Hanwag Alaska GTX)

The weather conditions seem to require lighter, more breathable, non-leather shoes. Still I can see the purpose of a firmer sole for the hike.

What kind of shoes would you recommend for an active trip to Costa Rica, including a jungle hike?

Comment: What kind of terrain? Pure jungle, or up a volcano or other mountains, or along a lot of beach? (like in Corcovado)

Comment: If they recommend B/C shoes they will have a reason for that and you should not go lower. Remember that the shoes also serve to protect your ankles and feet from injuries and cuts. Stinky feet is a downside that you might have to accept, bring a pair of light shoes for after the hike. I once saw a boot in the mesh style that was pioneered by the salomon techamphibian but was unable to find it now.

Comment: I don't know about those particular conditions, but I've found 'trail running' shoes useful for hiking as well as being lightweight. Of course they don't provide all the protection of hiking boots.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: there will be a hike through the jungle in Osa Peninsula, but there will be some mountain hiking around San Isidro as well.
Maybe I should get separate shoes for both types of hikes, but I was wondering if there are firmer shoes that are particularly suited to a tropical climate instead of an arctic climate

Comment: This question might be better asked on [outdoors.se].

Answer (score 1):

In the end I chose to buy a pair of the lesser known Hanwag Togiak GTX shoes.

They seem much lighter and more breathable than the other shoes I've seen, while they are still in the B category.

Other shoes I considered are Jack Wolfskin Impulse Texapore O2+Id, Lowa Phoenix GTX Mid and the Hanwag Comox GTX, all of which are in the B category.

I found that the B/C category doesn't contain any shoes that seem suited for the trip I'm about to do, so I think the B category is the closest I can get.

Comment: It would be great if you could comment after your trip on how useful you found those shoes.

Comment: I will @mts, thanks for the advices you guys have given in the comments